# Change falling hearts background animation to use multiple, random images

Tags: javascript, html, image, animation, canvas

My question is for this plugin: https://codepen.io/bferioli/pen/qEGaPp

I'm trying to use several pictures in this canvas but I can't find how to. Basically, what I want is to display randomly a selection of images (10 or more) instead of only the heart.

I think I have to edit this part of that CodePen snippet:

```js
  heartHeight: 60,
  heartWidth: 64,
  hearts: [],
  heartImage: 'http://i58.tinypic.com/ntnw5.png',
  maxHearts: 8,
  minScale: 0.4,
  draw: function() {
    this.setCanvasSize();
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.hearts.length; i++) {
      var heart = this.hearts[i];
      heart.image = new Image();
      heart.image.style.height = heart.height;
      heart.image.src = this.heartImage;
      this.ctx.globalAlpha = heart.opacity;
      this.ctx.drawImage (heart.image, heart.x, heart.y, heart.width, 
      heart.height);
    }
```

**HERE IS MY CODE** visible here: https://codepen.io/Le-future/pen/eKaarK

```
  var imagesArray = ["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAABlBMVEX/4AL9+dVNpYF7AAAATElEQVR4nO3BQREAAAwCIO1fein28YB0XQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAvXXdlRQHDJgU7pgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEUpczS1QJ41AAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC", "https://www.apyart.com/2226-thickbox_default/bleu-ciel-500ml.jpg"];

  var HeartsBackground = {
            heartHeight: 60,
            heartWidth: 64,
            hearts: [],
            heartImage: 'http://i58.tinypic.com/ntnw5.png',
            maxHearts: 8,
            minScale: 0.4,
            draw: function() {
              this.setCanvasSize();
              this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
              for (var i = 0; i < this.hearts.length; i++) {
                var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // 0...3
                var heart = this.hearts[i];
                heart.image = new Image();
                heart.image.style.height = heart.height;
                heart.image.src = imagesArray[num];
                this.ctx.globalAlpha = heart.opacity;
                this.ctx.drawImage (heart.image, heart.x, heart.y, heart.width, heart.height);
              }
      this.move();
    },
    move: function() {
      for(var b = 0; b < this.hearts.length; b++) {
        var heart = this.hearts[b];
        heart.y += heart.ys;
        if(heart.y > this.h) {
          heart.x = Math.random() * this.w;
          heart.y = -1 * this.heartHeight;
        }
      }
    },
    setCanvasSize: function() {
      this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      this.w = this.canvas.width;
      this.h = this.canvas.height;
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.canvas = $('#canvas')[0];

      if(!this.canvas.getContext)
        return;

      this.setCanvasSize();
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

      for(var a = 0; a < this.maxHearts; a++) {
        var scale = (Math.random() * (1 - this.minScale)) + this.minScale;
        this.hearts.push({
          x: Math.random() * this.w,
          y: Math.random() * this.h,
          ys: Math.random() + 1,
          height: scale * this.heartHeight,
          width: scale * this.heartWidth,
          opacity: scale,
          image: imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*imagesArray.length)]
        });
      }

      setInterval($.proxy(this.draw, this), 30);
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(function(){
    HeartsBackground.initialize();
  });
```

Comment: This is a scope that's probably too large to answer. There are several different ways to do this. Give it a shot, and let us know how you would like to do it, and then we can help if you run into any specific problems.

Comment: @zfrisch thanks for your answer, I tried to edit that code and look the result : https://codepen.io/Le-future/pen/eKaarK I definitely don't know how to solve this...

Comment: I suggest starting by changing the snippet to use just one of the images you want to randomly choose from. Then you can test to see if your image-loading code is working, without worrying about a bug in your random-choice code.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane To be honest, I'm lost, spent 2 days on that stuff, I'm pretty sure it's simple but no, I can't find what's wrong, I can display one image or have the blinking ones like on my pen, but not the result I'm looking for...

Comment: EDITED MY CODE ABOVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is to add an array outside of the heartsBackground loop. it will be used to store the image of each of the 8 objects.

`var heartsOutside = ["","","","","","","",""]`

I then check to see if the outside array contains data and load if exists

```
if(heartsOutside[i] != ""){num = heartsOutside[i]}
```

Then store the data to the outside array for the next loop

```
heartsOutside[i] = num;
```

I also added a step to clear the heart image upon reaching the bottom of the fall in the move function

```
heartsOutside[b] = ""
```

```js
      var imagesArray = ["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAABlBMVEX/4AL9+dVNpYF7AAAATElEQVR4nO3BQREAAAwCIO1fein28YB0XQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAvXXdlRQHDJgU7pgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEUpczS1QJ41AAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC", "https://www.apyart.com/2226-thickbox_default/bleu-ciel-500ml.jpg"];
      var heartsOutside = ["","","","","","","",""]
      var HeartsBackground = {
                heartHeight: 60,
                heartWidth: 64,
                hearts: [],
                heartImage: 'http://i58.tinypic.com/ntnw5.png',
                maxHearts: 8,
                minScale: 0.4,
                draw: function() {
                  this.setCanvasSize();
                  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
                  for (var i = 0; i < this.hearts.length; i++) {
                    
                    
                    //else{
                    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // 0...4
                    if(heartsOutside[i] != ""){num = heartsOutside[i]}
                    var heart = this.hearts[i];
                    heartsOutside[i] = num;
                    heart.image = new Image();
                    heart.image.style.height = heart.height;
                    
                    heart.image.src = imagesArray[num];
                    this.ctx.globalAlpha = heart.opacity;
                    this.ctx.drawImage (heart.image, heart.x, heart.y, heart.width, heart.height);
                  }
          this.move();
        },
        move: function() {
          for(var b = 0; b < this.hearts.length; b++) {
            var heart = this.hearts[b];
            heart.y += heart.ys;
            if(heart.y > this.h) {
              heart.x = Math.random() * this.w;
              heart.y = -1 * this.heartHeight;
              heartsOutside[b] = ""
            }
          }
        },
        setCanvasSize: function() {
          this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
          this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
          this.w = this.canvas.width;
          this.h = this.canvas.height;
        },
        initialize: function() {
          this.canvas = $('#canvas')[0];

          if(!this.canvas.getContext)
            return;

          this.setCanvasSize();
          this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

          for(var a = 0; a < this.maxHearts; a++) {
            var scale = (Math.random() * (1 - this.minScale)) + this.minScale;
            this.hearts.push({
              x: Math.random() * this.w,
              y: Math.random() * this.h,
              ys: Math.random() + 1,
              
              height: scale * this.heartHeight,
              width: scale * this.heartWidth,
              opacity: scale,
              image: imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*imagesArray.length)]
            });
          }

          setInterval($.proxy(this.draw, this), 30);
        }
      };

      $(document).ready(function(){
        HeartsBackground.initialize();
      });
```

```css
body {
  background: #B7004E;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)